# How can i set the opacity of a WriteableBitmap in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am now working on a image processing function. I am trying to overlay two image in wp7. In the photoshop, there is a opacity option when blending two images, i would like to do similar in wp7. But i am get no idea on how to set the opacity using WriteableBitmap.

Can anyone help to give me some light on how to set the opacity of a WriteableBitmap in windows phone 7?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no opacity option because WriteableBitmap is not an image processing class. You have to read pixels from WriteableBitmap and change alpha values (I guess alpha occurs every 4 byte in the `byte[]` array).

If you don't need to change images, but just need to display them with an opacity/transparency effect, you may consider using shaders (HLSL).

Last of all, take a look at [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/). You can blit two WriteableBitmaps with some blending options.